# Open a view in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In a pipeline script i am able to get a view in the public area of jenkins like this

```
println Jenkins.get().getView("TECHNICAL") // => hudson.model.AllView@787d286c[view/TECHNICAL/]
```

But I need one of the views in "My views", the path of that view in the browser is
"http://servername:8080/user/myusername/my-views/view/Overview/"

The following doesn't work:

```
println Jenkins.get().getView("/user/myusername/my-views/view/Overview") // => null
```

How can I open a view in My views ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User views are part of [User](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html) object embedded in `UserProperties`. Please check the following script

```
script {
    def username = 'admin'
    def user = User.get(username, false, null)
    if (user != null) {
      for(def property: user.getAllProperties()) {
          if(property instanceof hudson.model.MyViewsProperty) {
              for(def view : property.getViews()){
                println(view.name)
              }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to enumerate ? No path for direct access ?

Comment: AFAIK no. One improvement is you can do `property.getView​(String name)` instead of `property.getViews()`. Or else you can consider using the ApI. 
`http://localhost:8080/user/admin/my-views/view/ycrview/api/json`